# How to hide menu button for custom resource in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have model `User` and resources for it in AA - `users` and `suspicious users`.

How i can hide menu button for `suspicious users`?

I tried `menu false` but it doesn't work with this custom resource.

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register User, as: 'Suspicious Users' do
  menu false
```

Comment: according to AA [menu documentation](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#customize-the-menu) `menu false` should work.

Comment: just guessing, but do you want to hide the User menu item based on a propery of the currently logged in user? What Samphat Badhe says is correct.